# Computing the entropic risk measure symbolically in MMA

Tags: simplifying-expressions, probability-or-statistics, series-expansion, distributions

Using the link [Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropic_value_at_risk), it is possible to compute the entropic risk measure as follows:
$$
EVaR=\text{inf}_{z>0}\{z^{-1}\ln\left(\frac{M_X(z)}{\alpha}\right)\},
$$
wherein $X$ is a random variable having a given distribution, $\alpha$ is the confidence level, and $M_X(z)$ is the moment generating function (MGF).

Hopefully since we have a command for MDF, I write the following lines for the normal distribution:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
X = NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]];
Mgf = MomentGeneratingFunction[X, z]
Mgf1 = Mgf/\[Alpha] // FullSimplify;
Mgf2 = PowerExpand[Log[Mgf1], 
   Assumptions -> {z >= 0, \[Mu] >= 0, \[Sigma] >= 0, 
     0 < \[Alpha] < 1}];
EVaR = Refine[1/z Mgf2,
   Assumptions -> {z >= 0, \[Mu] >= 0, \[Sigma] >= 0, 
     0 < \[Alpha] < 1}] // FullSimplify
```

Unfortunately this does not lead to the correct value $\sigma  \sqrt{-2 \log (\alpha )}+\mu$.

Can anyone give some hints here how we can get the results or get rid of the $z$ variable in my code output?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
assumptions = DistributionParameterAssumptions[X] && 0 < α < 1 && z > 0;
Assuming[assumptions,
 FullSimplify @ Minimize[{EVaR, assumptions}, z]
]
(* {μ + σ Sqrt[Log[1/α^2]], {z -> Sqrt[Log[1/α^2]]/σ}} *)
```

**edit**

Since Minimize is not going to work for every distribution, you can use this function to get the EVaR for numeric distributions and numeric values of `α`:

```
EntropicValueAtRisk[dist_?DistributionParameterQ, α_?NumericQ] /; 
  NumericQ[RandomVariate[dist]] := Module[{
   mgf = MomentGeneratingFunction[dist, \[FormalZ]],
   assumptions
  },
   assumptions = Simplify[DistributionParameterAssumptions[dist] && \[FormalZ] > 0 && mgf > 0];
   NMinimize[
    {
     FullSimplify[1/\[FormalZ] Log[mgf/α], Assumptions -> assumptions],
     assumptions
    },
    \[FormalZ]
   ]
 ];

EntropicValueAtRisk[UniformDistribution[], 0.5]
(* {0.815172, {\[FormalZ] -> 5.26208}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks. This line helps to get the results but why the whole code still does not give a same output for the `UniformDistribution[{a,b}]` as in the link of the question?

Comment: It just looks like `Minimize` can't find the minimum for that expression, unfortunately. If you give specific values for `a`, `b` and `α`, you can use `NMinimize` to find the minimum.

Comment: Your edited response sounds much more useful. Is it possible to `Compile` your function so as to gain some speed while we call it in a loop?

Comment: `NMinimize` already compiles expressions internally wherever it can, so there's little point in trying to write your own compilation of this code since `NMinimize` is going to be the slowest step. The only optimization that makes sense here, is to use symbolic results from `Minimize` where possible (and then substitute parameter values) and only use `NMinimize` where necessary.

Comment: Another optimization you could attempt, is to pre-compute a number of values of `α` for a given distribution and then use `Interpolation` to interpolate those values so you can get other `α` values more quickly (approximately). `FunctionInterpolation` might also work here (though it can be a bit flaky sometimes).